# Computation of a specific residue map related to an elliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a number field $k$ and let $O$ be the distinguished $k$-rational point of $E$. Let $K$ be the function field of $E$. By Milne's *Etale cohomology* we have an exact sequence

$$0 \rightarrow \mathrm{Br}\,E \rightarrow \mathrm{Br}\, K \rightarrow \bigoplus_{x \in E^{(1)}}\mathrm{Hom}(k(x),\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}),$$

where $E^{(1)}$ denote the set of closed points of $E$, and $k(x)$ is the residue field of the closed point $x$. I am interested in the image of the residue map

$$\chi = \chi_O: \mathrm{Br}\, K \rightarrow \mathrm{Hom}(k(x),\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$$

with respect to the $k$-point $O$. By Colliot-Thelene and Skorobogatov's *The Brauer-Grothendieck group*, Theorem 3.6.2,

> (Witt) Let $R$ be a henselian discrete valuation ring with fraction field $K$ and perfect residue field $k$. Then there is a split exact sequence
> $$0 \rightarrow \mathrm{Br}\,k \rightarrow \mathrm{Br}\,K \rightarrow \mathrm{Hom}(k,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow 0.$$

I'm trying to fit my situation into the one stated in the theorem.

1. Is the function field $K$ of $E$ the fraction field of some henselian DVR?

I did some searching and found out that for the (affine) elliptic curve given by the equation $f(X,Y) = 0$, its field of rational function is the fraction field of $k[X,Y]/(f)$, but I don't think this is a DVR.

2. Does the residue field of $O$ happen to be $K$ itself?

I'm trying to show that the image of $\chi$ should be zero, but I'm not sure if this is even right.

Comment: Let me give you two pointers without claiming to be able to really resolve the meat of the question. 1. The DVRs present here are the local rings of closed points of $E$. I don't even have a passing familiarity with the henselian property, so I can't tell you whether they're henselian or not (or under what conditions they would be that aren't just the definition of henselian). 2. No, the residue of $O$ is $k$, this is the definition of a $k$-rational point.

Comment: @KReiser As always, thank you for your comments! I'll think about them.